# Вопросительное местоимение в условном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Что если мы сходим погулять сегодня?

Почему после "что" не стоит запятая? Есть ли в ней острая необходимость?

Answer (score 1):

Постановка запятой в сочетании ***что если*** можно определить **по интонации,** но при этом сама интонация соответствует определенной **семантике.**

**Исходная структура**: что (будет, может быть),  если...
Местоимение ЧТО выполняет функцию **частицы** в вопросительном предложении.

При постановке запятой **ударение** падает на местоимение ЧТО.

**Примеры**

***Что если*** мы сходим погулять сегодня?  Это обращение с нерешительной просьбой

***А что*** если нам еще раз голубую змейку позвать? П. Бажов, Голубая змейка.  Это предложение (давай позовем).

***А что***, если устроить этим явно враждебным подлодкам маленькую ответную диверсию? Г. Адамов, Тайна двух океанов. Это предложение-вопрос (может быть, устроим?).

*Ч**то, если** он начал о чём-то догадываться? Ч. Айтматов, Плаха.*  (Это опасение, а вдруг...)

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_759&layout=item

Таки образом, здесь просматриваются два варианта: (1) ЧТО является безударной частицей  (запятая не нужна) и (2) ЧТО выделено ударением в устной речи и запятой на письме.

Во втором случае в большей степени выражаются сомнения, опасения и другие чувства (чтО будет, чтО было бы...), поэтому местоимение ЧТО выделяется **ударением**. Например: ***Что, если*** бы я не бросил ее? И. Бунин, Темные аллеи.

Что касается паузы,то она отсутствует в обоих вариантах (слитное произношение более удобно).

**Об авторском выборе**

Можно еще добавить следующее: постановка запятой, вероятно, во многих случаях является авторским выбором, например:

(1) ***Что если*** мы сходим погулять сегодня? **Может быть**, мы сходим погулять сегодня?

(2) ***Что, если*** мы сходим погулять сегодня? **А как ты смотришь на то, если** мы сходим погулять сегодня?

В первом случае это общий вопрос, сочетание ***что если*** соответствует вводном слову ***может быть.***

Во втором  случае как бы присутствует самостоятельная вопросительная часть, представленная местоимением ЧТО, которая по смыслу  может соответствовать предложению.